# Custom back button vs multiple user paths

Tags: website-design, navigation, information-architecture, back-button, breadcrumbs

I'm working on a Hotel chain website that has custom back buttons on their hotel pages. The back button takes users to the previous level in the navigation.

E.g: A user in "Hotel page" clicks "<- Back" and goes to "Hotels in Madrid"

This has been working fine, but now the site is going to grow. We're going to introduce changes in the Information Architecture and new pages like Hotel collections, Restaurant pages, etc. This means that there will be **multiple paths for users to get to the hotel pages**, so my question is... What should happen to the custom back button?

I was thinking of 2 options:

- a) Remove the custom back button because it adds too much complexity.
- b) Make the button dynamic (e.g: <-Back to [dynamic_copy]) and try to
  establish a set of rules depending on the users previous path.

What do you think? Do you have another idea? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

- If you remove the back button, have a breadcrumb or add one.
  It is essential for the complex navigation of your users
- The back button should redirect the user back to the previous level but not previous URLs parameter like the back button of your navigator (like the previous anchor)

hope this help :)

Comment: Thanks. Adding a breadcrumb presents the same problem because there would be multiple possible breadcrumbs / user paths to get to the page.